# In PHP and C#, why foreach doesn't have a built-in check for null array/list?

Tags: c#, php, programming-languages

In PHP, C# and may be other languages, why aren't languages developed to reduce writing code that isn't really necessary?

Why for example foreach perform a loop on null array or list?

I'm not a professional programmer, but I think this a common sense.

Thank you.

Comment: null and empty list are 2 different things! For empty arrays, it works just fine in PHP. https://onecompiler.com/php/3ypahhnbm

Comment: I already updated the content.

Comment: Do you think it is valid to treat a null array/list variable the same as a variable that points to an empty (no items) array/list? I'm not sure it is.

Comment: why can't you check to before the loop that array/list it `null` or `Count == 0` ? If you still want to explore why a null/empty check is not there, you can raise an issue in the Dotnet repo on GitHub.

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai Can you define what is a _null array_ ?

Comment: This what I'm saying. Each time I do a loop I've to check for null array, which it shouldn't be needed if the foreach enhanced a bit.

Comment: Why do you need to check each time? Why are your arrays and lists always potentially null? I almost never have to check if my array/list is null.

Comment: They are not always null, but if I read lines from an empty textbox, it maybe null. Is it that hard to implement check for null in foreach?

Comment: I think this is a valid question. "Why was language feature X implemented this way?" is not opinion-based.

Comment: It would be super super simple to implement such a feature if you wanted to blanketly treat any null array/list variable as an empty list. I don't really agree that this is necessarily a good idea. As far as I'm aware, Microsoft features usually start at [negative 100 points](http://stronglyemergent.com/blog/2013/negative-100-points/), meaning that there needs to be a strong reason to make the change.

Comment: P.S. What do you mean "read lines from an empty textbox"? An empty textbox would have a single empty line in that case, surely?

Comment: This is just an example, but null array/list may exist.

Comment: Is it really such a common occurrence? And when such a null array or list exists, doesn't that value of null also have some meaning?

Comment: I think in C# it is allowed to have a nullable arrays, and useful sometimes. But again -and as I said in the thread- 'am not that professional in programming.

Comment: Answering your comment on my workaround here (_"I know how to avoid it, but I am asking why I have to avoid it? Why it's not a built-in feature?"_): 1) It would be a departure from the way the vast majority of .NET handles `null`. Microsoft even throws exceptions in the LINQ extension methods if the input enumerable is `null`. The overall experience would become less consistent IMHO. 2) Many developers would want to know if they've passed a `null` where they intended to pass a list/array, so that it can be caught by unit tests or revealed at runtime. 1/

Comment: Advocating for treating `null` enumerables as empty in `foreach` would mean that it becomes necessary to manually check that your list isn't null. This would also result in double checking: 1. You manually write a guard statement to throw an exception if the list is null. 2. The compiler generates code with a null check. 3) `null` can have its own meaning separately to empty. For example, if I make a PATCH API, `null` might mean "not sent for change by the client" whereas empty would mean "change this list to empty in the database". 4) Many times we generate lists and foreach over them in 2/

Comment: in the same method. Other times, we know our enumerables are not null. It's not really the default state (from a design perspective, not technical perspective) for an enumerable to be null. We usually assign values to them. Even `"".Split(',')` produces a `string[]` that contains one item: an empty string. In these cases, adding an additional and unnecessary null check simply makes the code run a little bit slower for no gain.  -- You would need a very strong reason with a demonstrably large benefit to the entire community as a whole for a change like this to be made.

Comment: I think for those on .NET 6 projects, nullable reference types enhancements may assist in your issue by outputting warning. You can turn on by adding this in your project <Nullable>enable</Nullable>:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Answer (score 3):

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

**Because foreach is not an assembly level instruction**

The `foreach` keyword is "syntactical sugar" from the language, not something that really ends up in the generated code. The code

```cs
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
// ... fill list
foreach(var s in myList)
{
   // ...
}
```

is actually translated to

```
IEnumerator it = myList.GetEnumerator();

while (it.MoveNext())
{
    string s = it.Current;
    // ...
}
```

In this piece of code, it would be quite ugly to check `myList` for null, as it would require the introduction of a nested if. And `myList` doesn't need to be a simple variable, it can be any type of expression or even a method call. It wouldn't be *impossible*, but would complicate things for the compiler considerably and add extra code even for cases where it wouldn't be required.

In general, it is also a good idea to let the program crash in case of an error, because it allows detection of errors early. The .NET runtime generally exhibits the concept of throwing early instead of attempting to conceal an error as long as possible. Whether that is "better" is a philosophical question and there are other languages going other paths here, but for C#, that behavior is used consistently throughout.

While rare, the list can technically be a value type, where a null test would be wrong, requiring the compiler to make a type test.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see why we can't implement if (mylist is not null) in here?

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai As I wrote: It would be possible to do it, but it would complicate things for the compiler, and generate more code even if the test would not be required. I've added some more considerations.

Answer (score 1):

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

If it really irritates you, perhaps you could work around this using an extension method. Because it's an extension method, you can call it even on a `null` array or list.

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source is null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

You can use this method like so:

```cs
List<string> nullList = null;
foreach (var entry in nullList.EmptyIfNull())
{
    // code here
}
```

Of course you could write this without the extension method too:

```cs
foreach (var entry in nullList ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
{
    // code here
}
```

This won't throw an exception because the extension method ([null coalescing operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/null-coalescing-operator-in-c-sharp/) in the second example) prevents the enumerable evaluated by `foreach` from being `null`.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DJZ39698)

Comment: I know how to avoid it, but I am asking why I have to avoid it? Why it's not a built-in feature?

Comment: @KhalidAlmannai it doesn't even sound desirable as a feature; if you don't want to have NREs: make your values non-null. In modern C#, the compiler will help you with that (NRTs)